# Show a sequence of a sequence is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n)$ be a positive, strictly increasing, convergent sequence in $\mathbb R$.
Show that the sequence $$(x_1^n +\cdots+x_n^n)^{1/n}$$ converges.

At first I tried to show that the sequence is monotone, but some calculations have shown that it is not. Now I think I need to somehow show that limsup $\leqslant$ liminf or that the sequence has two subsequences that converge to the same value, but I have no idea where to start with either approach.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: under the hypotheses, $x_n^n \le x_1^n +\cdots+x_n^n \le nx_n^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I totally forgot about squeeze theorem!